Metric set with empty interior, Baire's theorem
I'm solving the following problem:
Let $(M,d)$ be a complete metric space, with $M=\cup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$, where $F_n$ is closed. Show that there is an $F_n$ such that $int(F_n) \neq \emptyset$
My attempt was to use Baire's Theorem to show, by contradiction, that $int(M) = \emptyset$ if $int(F_n) = \emptyset$ for all $n$.
My question is: Is this a contradiction? I mean, is there a way for a complete metric space to have empty interior? If not, why? And if it's possible, then how do I solve the problem?
The version of Baire that I'm using is: Let $X$
a complete metric space. Let $\{X_n\}_n$
a sequence of subsets. Suppose $Int(\overline{Xn})=\emptyset$
for all $n$
. Then $Int(\cup_{n∈\mathbf{N}} X_n)=\emptyset$
.

No non-empty space has an empty interior as a subspace of itself: It contains a nonempty open subset, namely itself.

As Ben Steffan said in his comment, a non-empty topological space $M$ cannot have empty interior, since $M\not=\emptyset$ is itself an open set. So you $\textit{do}$ get a contradiction: since each $F_n$ is closed, then $\overline{F_n}=F_n$ and, as you said, $M=int\left(\cup_{n=1}^\infty F_n\right)=\emptyset$ by Baire's Theorem.
